# Play Application runs on port 443 but nothing resolves from a browser

Tags: https, playframework

We have a Play application running on a Linux box that resolves to port 443 instead of port 80 or port 9000.

The application is up and running without errors - there are no errors in the SSH console.

Port 80 is disabled (HTTP) but we want to have the web application appear in the browser using port 443 (HTTPS).

We have the application.conf file set up to use the correct port as well as the correct keystore path and keystore type (JKS).

Since there are no errors, we would like to know what we can do to correct this situation.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Is the application accessible from the host itself? What is the result of running `curl http://localhost:443` inside the host itself? Is there any firewall wrongly configured blocking the access from outside?

Comment: Did you check any and all firewalls etc? That's the most likely source of your problem. Also, check if you're using the right combination of protocol and port (`https://example.com:443` != `http://example.com:443`)

Comment: @marcospereira - the result is `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused`

Comment: Did you have a firewall enabled? Maybe ufw/iptables or another one?

Comment: `ufw` is disabled.  We can connect to localhost and port 443 (HTTPS) -- `curl -ipv4 -v https://localhost`.  However, When we attempt to curl the IP address, it fails to connect however.  We use `curl -ip4v -v https://myipaddress -k` (use `-k` to skip the certificate for now), we get a Failed to Connect error - `curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.`